# mongoose-paginate-v2 + mongoose-lean-virtuals : How to set virtuals param for the lean method

Tags: mongodb, mongoose-schema

I am using both plugins mongoose-paginate-v2  and mongoose-lean-virtuals in a model schema. And I want to set `{ virtuals: ['stockStatus'] }` to lean method when I query mongoDb using paginate method.

I have set lean : true in pagination options, but the query doesn’t return my virtual field.

My API controller :

```
Product.paginate({}, paginationOptions(req, 'productsList'))
    .then(result => {
        res.json({ message: "Products list",...result});
    })
    .catch (error => {
        next(error);
    })
```

```
exports.paginationOptions = (req, docName, isLean) => {
    const options = {       
        lean : true,
        page: req.query.page,
        limit: req.query.limit,
        sort: { _id: req.query.sort },
        customLabels:   {
            totalDocs: 'itemCount',
            docs: docName,
            limit: 'perPage',
            page: 'currentPage',
            nextPage: 'next',
            prevPage: 'prev',
            totalPages: 'pageCount',
            pagingCounter: 'slNo'    
        }
    }
    if (isLean === false ) {options.lean = false}
    return (!req.query.page || !req.query.limit) ?  {...options, pagination: false} : options

};
```

Model

```
const ProductSchema = new Schema({
  SKU :  { type: String, index: true, unique: true },
  title: String,
  description: String,
  status: String,
  brand: String,
  supplier: String,
  stockUnit: String,
  manufacturer: String,
  manufacturerReference: String
},
{
  timestamps: true
})
ProductSchema.virtual('stockStatus').get(function() {
  return 1
})

ProductSchema.plugin(mongooseLeanVirtuals);
ProductSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema)
```

Comment: Please see [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/5211833). Also note that people on Stack Overflow tend to answer questions in tags they follow, so adding relevant tags (like [tag:mongodb] here) helps to expose your question to more people.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution :

lean option can take a boolean or an object.
To specify a virtual prop, simply assign `lean : { virtuals: ['stockStatus'] }`